# accessing WebInvoke UriTemplate in WCF, I need the template string

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, uritemplate, webinvoke

I have in WCF
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "etcetc"

I need to access the string "etcetc" for use in some of my business logic, not sure if this is possible or not?  Where is it stored in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like below to access these attributes :

```
 MethodBase method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
 WebInvoke attr = (UriTemplate )method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebInvoke), true)[0] ;
 string value = attr.UriTemplate ;
```

And to answer your second question : where it is stored ? So it is basically part of your metadata in compiled assembly.